How to stream the audio output on one android device to multiple others?
I am trying to create an app that shares audio between phones to create a simoultaneous "synced audio" experience. This would require connecting multiple devices, taking the audio output from one device (Audio Capture), and streaming the bytes to the other devices in real-time.
I have found the Nearby Connections API, which supports sending a stream, but I cannot figure out how to get the stream from the device's audio to be transformed into something Nearby Connections may send. I am open to other methods not involving Nearby Connections, but I prefer this method as it appears to be low-latency.

This is actually a lot harder to do than you'd think, since fractions of a second off will cause them to be out of sync.  This is something that audio manufacturers put serious time and effort into.  I would look for a pre-existing solution you can use or buy, rather than trying to write it yourself.
